# getArgument get nullexception when fragment create view 2nd time

Tags: android, android-fragments

By default, the listview fragment will be shown 1st on my activity

Here is my activity:

```
public class SecondActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction tran = manager.beginTransaction();
        ListViewFragment fr = new ListViewFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable("Object", getIntent().getParcelableExtra("ObjectFromCategory"));
        fr.setArguments(bundle);
        tran.addToBackStack(null);
        tran.replace(R.id.places_fragment_cointainer, fr, "ListView");
        tran.commit();
        //handleFragmentCycle();
    }
```

Then in ListviewFragment I get argument:

```
public class ListViewFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
    private TextView mTxtMapView;
    private Category mObject;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_places_listview, container,false);
        mTxtMapView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txt_mapview);
        mObject = getArguments().getParcelable("Object");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), mObject.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mTxtMapView.setOnClickListener(this);
        return v;
    }
```

and here is my MapViewFragment:

```
public class MapViewFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

    TextView txtListView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_places_mapview, container, false);
        FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
        MapFragment supportMapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mapwhere, supportMapFragment).commit();
        txtListView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_listview);
        txtListView.setOnClickListener(this);
        return v;

    }
```

At first time ListViewFragment is created, I can get the argument successfully, but then I get null when I change to MapViewFragment then change back to ListViewFragment. I figure out a solution that I should pass an int value in bundle to detect if ListViewFragment is created from Activity or MapViewFragment. But I dont think it is a good solution cuz I still want to get the Category Objecct,so I want to hear if anybody have a better solution for this case. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your object to `SharePreference` using [gjson](https://github.com/google/gson) in your Activity.
Then in Fragment, you retrieve your object from `SharePreference`. 
After that, you will never get `null` object in your `Fragment`

===
This is the way to save and retrieve the object from `SharePreference`
**Creating**

```
SharedPreferences  mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);//Creating shared preference
```

**For save object**

```
Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(myObject); // myObject - instance of MyObject
prefsEditor.putString("Object", json);
prefsEditor.commit();
```

**For retrieve object**

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = mPrefs.getString("Object", "");
MyObject obj = gson.fromJson(json, MyObject.class);
```